# find: missing argument to `-exec' in Ubuntu Server 18.4

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu, server

I was helped with a command, but it doesn't seem to be working. This is the command:

```
find /var/www/HernandezW/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {}\;
```

The shell return error messages:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

How can I fix it to be able to install WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding space after `{}`:

```
find /var/www/HernandezW/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
```